# Odd behavior of ROW_NUMBER() query

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, indexing, amazon-redshift, row-number

With the purpose of adding an index to a table in Redshift with more than 24 million rows, I have created a view with the following code:

```
create view as 
select row_number() over (partition by 1) as rnum,
table.*
from table
```

Which apparently, worked well. Now, when I'm interested on retrieving the index of certain row:

```
select * from view
where eventid = '2902173565107421189'
```

I get this output:

| rnum | eventid |
| --- | --- |
| 6288983 | 290217356510742118 |

But if I perform a reverse search using the same 'rnum' index I got from the previous query:

```
select * from view
where rnum = 6288983
```

I get a completely different 'eventid':

| rnum | eventid |
| --- | --- |
| 6288983 | 2923737753109659648 |

And this is happening all the time. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't know Redshift but logically your row number is applied completely arbitrarily. Can you not add an auto-increment/identity column?

Comment: Same answer here that the one given for @HaH. It is not arbitrarily sorted. Yes, I could add an auto-increment ID, but I was curious about this issue.

Comment: It may *appear* consistent for the test you have run, but it is not guaranteed to be so, and indeed you have proved yourself it is not since a different query execution plan results in a different value.

Comment: What are you actually wanting to achieve? You say that you are "adding an index to a table", but Amazon Redshift does not support indexes. What is your actual goal? (That is, _what_ are you wanting to achieve, rather than _how?_)